# AS3: How to access data in XMLListCollection using ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I'm using an XMLListCollection for a spark ComboBox, inspired by this link

http://blog.shortfusion.com/index.cfm/2009/4/15/FlexAS3-Custom-ComboBox-for-Countries-with-XML

The XMLListCollection is defined here:

```
public class ComboBox_Country extends ComboBox {

    private var Country:XML=new XML(
        <countries>
         <country code="US" iso="840" label="United States" />
         <country code="CA" iso="124" label="Canada" />
         <country code="GB" iso="826" label="United Kingdom" />
                     ....
         <country code="ZM" iso="894" label="Zambia" />
         <country code="ZW" iso="716" label="Zimbabwe" />
        </countries>);

    public function ComboBox_Country() {
        dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(Country.children());
        labelField = '@label';
    }
```

and called in mxml as:

```
<mycomp:ComboBox_Country id="countryComboBox" width="100%"/>
```

When the user makes a selection, I can get the index from: `countryComboBox.selectedIndex`. But, I need the string for the country, and I'm not sure how to extract that from an XMLListCollection. When I look in the debugger I see:

[image]

Let's say the user selected index 2 (e.g. United Kingdom). What would I need to type into the debugger to return `United Kingdom`? I've tried things like:

```
countryComboBox.Country.getItemAt(2)
countryComboBox.Country.getItemAt(2).label
countryComboBox.Country[2]
countryComboBox.Country.label.getItemAt(2)
etc...
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox have a property selectedItem which you probably should use. In this case selectedItem would be XML object. Read how you can get data from XML objects [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html).
In your case you can get label using

```
countryComboBox.selectedItem.@label
```

Comment: Thanks borisgolovnev, when I try that it returns: `XMLList (@121f5cf11)` in the debugger.

Comment: Why do you need this label in debugger? I tried that now and yes, it shows as XML in debugger, but if I trace() it, it returns a country name. This is because @ and other XML traversal methods are actually methods that you have to call in order to get data. Debugger does not do that.

Comment: I was just using the debugger as a tool to help figure out the right syntax to return the selected label. But yes, you're right, if I trace the code you show above it does provide the correct result. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure you populating the combo box correctly, normally you'd use a data provider (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS70f0d54f063b9b081aac8d1d1247252e4a0-8000.html)

Assuming that is displaying the data correctly for you, then you're pretty close

```
// Should give you the country object selected
var obj:Object = countryComboBox.selectedItem;

// You should also be able to use .code or .iso
return obj.label;
```

If `obj.label` doesn't work, you could try `obj['label'];`

Comment: As explained by borisgolovnev, the debugger can't call the needed XML traversal methods to return the data, so I tried to use trace for this solution as well. I found you need to add a `@` prefix to label above, so the trace commands would be: `trace(obj.@label);` and `trace(obj['@label']);` Thanks so much!